# One route, 2 different schemas validating payload in Hapi.js with Joi

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have 1 route, 2 different joi schemas and I want to be able to dynamically select which schema I use based on a field in the payload.

"One route, 2 schemas (Hapi.js with Joi)"

So for context I have a hapi route and am using joi validation "someSchema"
hapiRoute.js:

```
...
 "validate": {
        "payload": someSchema
 }
...
```

In schema.js:

```
function ChooseSchema(schemaA, schemaB) {
  return Joi.when(Joi.ref("payload.data.attributes.someField"), {
    "is": Joi.string().valid("fieldIsValue"),
    "then": schemaA,
    "otherwise": schemaB
  });
}
module.exports = {
"someSchema": ChooseSchema(schemaA, schemaB)
}
```

Where schemaA & schemaB are different

So I am trying to use "schemaA" if "someField" is equal to a value: "fieldIsValue", otherwise use schemaB.
Currently it is not getting this value "someField", and so just returning schemaB I believe

Comment: Why do you need two schemas?

Comment: Due to needing to have different validations for 2 different users

Comment: UPDATE: I was trying to choose schema once payload validation was technically already underway(at least from a hapi.js point of view) I believ. Which clearly Isn't allowed

Answer (score 0):

So here is something that worked: 
using "request.query..." in hapiRoute.js:

```
...
"onPostAuth": {
          "method": (request, hapi) => {
              request.query.someField= request.someInfo.somefield;
...
```

You can access this in schema.js like so:

```
function ChooseSchema(schemaA, schemaB) {
  return Joi.when(Joi.ref("$query.someField"), {
    "is": Joi.string().valid("fieldIsValue"),
    "then": schemaA,
    "otherwise": schemaB
  });
}
```

So basically we set a query string parameter and then in joi schema we can then use that value.